# onclick window.location.href won't work in Chrome or Safari

Tags: google-chrome, onclick

We have a downloads section and we're trying to track when a user downloads something. The downloads are linked as followed:

```
<a href="DOWNLOADURL" onclick="window.location.href='http://analytics.performable.com/v1/event?_n=EVENTID&_a=PORTALID&email=USEREMAIL'">TITLE OF DOWNLOAD</a>
```

It works fine in IE and FF but not Chrome (or any webkit browser) or Safari. I can live without Safari but it would be nice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try this:

```
<a href="DOWNLOADURL" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http://analytics.performable.com/v1/event _n=EVENTID&_a=PORTALID&email=USEREMAIL'; return false;">TITLE OF DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Comment: my mistake. it should have 'return false;' at the end to cancel the original link action. i've updated my answer to reflect this.